# Original Image from Canvas using Fabricjs

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I am creating an app in which we need to upload the image to the canvas and finally I need the original image from the canvas with the same height, width and size of the image I uploaded. Right now I can extract that image from the canvas but its quality is declining. So please help me get the original image from the canvas.

Comment: best way for this to  when you upload Image upload it to your s3 bucket or server in original size and load it into canvas and  then whenever you need later you can use it

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @khajaamin . But I want that image from the canvas. Is there a way to get that image out of the canvas?  Is there a property that helps me get that original image?